# Why MSBuild looks for pdb files when it is building an installshield project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, installshield-2011

I have added a basic MSI project to my vS2010 solution, it builds fine on my machine, but when I check in my code and request a build using TFS then it doesn't build and generates the following error:

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\InstallShield\2011\InstallShield.targets (68): OutputGroups item "e:\BldTmp\2\MyProject\My Project Build\Sources\My project\lib.proj.Countdowns\obj\x86\Release\lib.proj.Countdown.pdb" of "lib.proj.Countdown.debug symbols" does not appear to exist.

why MSBuild or SAB 2011 are looking for pdb file? I don't want to add pdb file to my installer. I have checked the path and I can see that the pdb file exist, but the build generates this error!!

Answer (score 1):

It will not be MSBuild generating this error, it will be InstallShield's Stand Alone Builder.

What you have most likely done is when adding the files for the MSI, you selected a folder and created a [dynamic file link](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpDynamicFileLinking.htm) which includes all files, or more specifically **doesn't exclude** any files. To fix this you should leave it as is, but adjust the [link settings](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/IDlgDynLinkP.htm) to exclude `*.pdb` files. Or you could delete the link and recreate the component manually, and manually add whichever files you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My VS solution contains several projects. When I include the primary output of some of the projects to my MSI project, this problem happens.So I am not using dynamic file link but I just drag the primary output of a project to the "Destination computer's files" pane. In this case how can I exclude the pdb?